# What is the best way to construct a SQL query that returns the block name for each bus point as it travels?

Tags: postgis, tracking

I have two datasets in postgres; 1) a bunch of points that represent bus locations 2) city block polygons.

Each bus has a unique ID and each block polygon has a field that has the block name in it.  As the bus moves throughout the day, what is the best way to construct a SQL query that returns the block name for each bus point as it travels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the blocks have no intersections and every of your buses can be inside the only one block at a time, you can try something like this:

```sql
SELECT b.*, bl.name 
FROM buses b, blocks bl 
WHERE ST_Within(b.the_geom, bl.the_geom)
```

While you have **a bunch** of points, it's very useful to keep last coordinates just in *buses* table (via triggers), instead of executing queries over all these points you mentioned.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. A lot easier than I thought ;-)